# Why is my column-count not working with Bootstrap in Chrome?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, google-chrome, css-multicolumn-layout

I tried displaying multiple buttons in columns using

```css
.columnized {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
}
```

and markup

```html
<div class="columnized col-md-6">
    <p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">text</button>
    </p>
    <!-- ... more buttons ... -->
</div>
```

but the entire div is showing like a line and all the `p`s looks like they are floated to the right.

It's curious that this works in `Firefox 28` and **even** `Internet Explorer 10` and not in `Chrome 33`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was using *Twitter*'s `Bootstrap` and the `.col-md-6` has defined `min-height` as `1px`, hence the thin line.

I managed to solve it by adding `min-height: initial` to my `columnized` class.

Hope this helps others that bump against this odd problem.

Comment: Yep this worked for me too. How did you figure out that `initial` would work?

Comment: Worked! Here Bootstrap keeps adding min-height property

Answer (score 5):

I also found that using

```
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
          page-break-inside: avoid;
               break-inside: avoid;
```

and

```
break-inside: avoid-column;
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
```

solved problems with content breaking vertically between columns.

The column-count tag is easier to implement than floating divs, the main difference being that column content is ordered vertically, while floated content is ordered horizontally. Hope this helps.